# high resolution sample rate on the iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

inside our app we have to sample something in a high resolution.

i have seen that the regular `NSTimer` in objective c , cant go under 50ms.

we need to sample in a rate of about 1ms at least .

this is so strange that there is no 1 way to sample in 1ms when the iphone processor is more that 1ghz !

i had 2 ideas: 1. do a `while(1)` that maybe will give me the clock, or, use accelerometer sample(is he that fast? ) , i am sure both are not ok .

any idea to this simple problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not simple task to implement precise timer of that resolution. To get highly precise timer you probably need to implement your own run loop. If it requires only single timer with now dynamic timer insertion/deletion then it's implementation rather simple.

As you said, run the while(...) loop and inside there you need to sleep for some time. This is the most tricky part, cause sometimes the previously actual elapsed time could be bigger/smaller then the actual one so you have to compensate it.

```
    while( running ) {

        gettimeofday(&t_start, NULL);
        {
            double sleep_time = cur_timer->_M->nextFireTime() - elapsedTime;
            if( sleep_time > 0 ) {
                Thread::sleep(sleep_time); //sleep time is in seconds
            }
        }
        gettimeofday(&t_end, NULL);

        elapsedTime += Utils::timeval_diff(t_end, t_start);

        if( running ) {
            gettimeofday(&t_start, NULL);
            {
                //perform all timer callbacks here
            }
            gettimeofday(&t_end, NULL);
        }

        elapsedTime += Utils::timeval_diff(t_end, t_start);
    }
```

This is very simplified version of my own runloop implementation. The main idea here is that you have to keep track of the actual elapsed time and compensate any time overflows.

Here is the sample output for the 1ms time step:

```
period: 0.001000 (0.001000)   elapsed: 0.001160 (0.001160)
period: 0.001000 (0.002000)   elapsed: 0.000988 (0.002148)
period: 0.001000 (0.003000)   elapsed: 0.000982 (0.003130)
period: 0.001000 (0.004000)   elapsed: 0.001003 (0.004133)
period: 0.001000 (0.005000)   elapsed: 0.001004 (0.005137)

.....

period: 0.001000 (4.280872)   elapsed: 0.001022 (4.299592)
period: 0.001000 (4.281872)   elapsed: 0.002627 (4.302219)
period: 0.001000 (4.282872)   elapsed: 0.000018 (4.302237)
period: 0.001000 (4.283872)   elapsed: 0.000266 (4.302503)
period: 0.001000 (4.284872)   elapsed: 0.001091 (4.303594)
period: 0.001000 (4.285872)   elapsed: 0.001026 (4.304620)
```

To get even more precise results run the timer on a separate thread with high priority.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but i couldnt understand many things you said, and the code itself. first, way cant i run the while(1) loop and do what i need in there? why i have to do the sleep? to let processor do other stuff?, and if i do, so why not just do the sleep() method for like 500us ? i couldnt understand what your code is trying to achieve anyway..

Comment: you can use while(1) but then you have to stop the run loop using break; you have too sleep the timer to control the time period.

Comment: ok i can see now. i was told to use NSDate for this also. is that ok too ?